# is there a way to create a instance

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, co

Since from `co@4.0+` we can use below statement

`var fn = co.wrap(fn*)`

to convert a generator into a regular function that returns a Promise.

Then I face a problem

`a.js`

```
var F = function *(a,b,c){
    this.a = yield this.getA(a);
    this.b = yield this.getB(b);
    this.c = yield this.getC(c);
}

F.prototype.getA = function * (a){
    //........
}
F.prototype.getB = function * (b){
    //........
}
F.prototype.getC = function * (c){
    //........
}
exports.F = F;
```

how to create a instance  in `b.js` by `co` .

---

@Bergi said it`s a bad practice

then I want to ask anthor question

```
function* F(){
  yield this.x = 2;
  yield this.y = 3;
}
var obj = {};
var f = F.bind(obj)();

f.next();
f.next();
f.next();

console.log(obj);
// { x: 2, y: 3 }
```

is it a bad  practice ?

Comment: Generators are no constructors, and `wrap` doesn't wrap constructors. Also see [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I just  re-edited my question . So what`s your opinion?

Comment: I don't know what your second script is supposed to do, so I can't say whether it's a bad practise and whether there's a better solution to the problem. It looks a bit overcomplicated, though.

Comment: The second script is supposed to create a instance of `F` . Because of `F` is a generator  so I can not use `new` to create a instance.

Comment: But why are you `yield`ing inside of `F` at all?

Comment: Good question - -!    `Constuctor`  should pure

Comment: `var f = F.bind(obj)();` is just `var f = F.call(obj);`